# python printing correct line in program

Tags: python

I am taking a Python programming course with this question on strings:

```
phrase = "HULK MAD"
phrase = phrase.lower()
phrase = phrase.title()
cut_phrase = phrase[:5]
new_phrase = ""

for char in phrase[5:]:
    if char == "m":
        new_phrase = cut_phrase + "Hungry"
    elif char == "a":
        new_phrase = cut_phrase + "Angry"
    elif char == "d":
        new_phrase = cut_phrase + "Smash"
    print(new_phrase)
```

Which prints:

```
Hulk Angry
Hulk Smash
```

I'm getting tripped up on the questions:

> What is the first, second, third, and fourth line printed by the code above? If a blank line is printed, write Blank. If there is no third line, write None.

The only question I got correct was the fourth line printing `None`. Would ALL lines first, second, third, and fourth all be `None` because there isn't a Python `print` statement inside the 1st - 4th lines of code????

Comment: You do `phrase = phrase.title()`. What's in `phrase` now? Then you do `for char in phrase[5:]:`: What does this make `char` in each iteration? Now that you know what `char` is, you can tell what will be printed. See the points about rubber-duck debugging in [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and stepping through your code to understand its behavior [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: I didnt write the program haha. Its a course I am taking where the instructor wrote the program

Comment: That is immaterial. You can debug any program, even if you didn't write it. In fact, understanding other people's code is an important skill (just like being able to debug your own code) for a programmer in any capacity

Comment: well isnt stackoverflow supposed to be a place where people can get help?

Comment: If you follow the ideas suggested in the links I shared, you can figure out why the code behaves the way it does pretty easily. My comment was just showing you how to help yourself in the future (give a man a fish etc.) Please see [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the output of that program:

```
(a blank string)
Hulk Angry
Hulk Smash
```

The question is asking about those lines of *output*, not about lines of *code*.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that. So the first line is a blank string. Where does the program output a blank string?

Comment: On the first iteration of the for loop, `char` is neither "m" nor "a" nor "d", so `new_phrase` retains its original value of a blank string.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that